# When and why should I clean the build in XCode

Tags: xcode

Every once in awhile, the solution to an aggravating problem in XCode is to hit Product → Clean, and this seems to clear some cache and problems disappear.

But what is it actually doing? And more importantly, WHEN should I be doing this? It seems to be necessary more often when dealing with Core Data, but I haven't really been tracking it.

As a side question, WHY is this necessary? XCode seems to do a lot of stuff in the background (autosave, autocompile, etc). Why doesn't this also just happen in the background?

Answer (score 0):

It's because there are a lot difference when you are working with a very very big project with a lot of files and objects. Imagine that you need an hour to recompile a entire project, so you will think before do this. But in our world, this is a fast task.

XCode use the `make` program. So, it compile only what was changed.

I can list same cases you need do this:

- Always you will create a App for App Store. This safety thing to do.
- Always you use the XCode Snapshot. I have bad time when I restore a project and build the app. XCode used old compiled files and a lot of time was lost to search it.
- Maybe when you restore a old code with git. Is the same idea of the Snapshot
- When you delete or rename a file in project. It don't delete the compiled file, so the program can work, but if you recompile, will see the errors.
- When you see that sometime the build have a strange behavior. Or only to have certain that XCode use only your newer files.

I don't remember exactly but i have seen the build use old `#defines`. Rebuilding can make you more safe about your program. But don't need do this all time.

Comment: But what exactly is "strange behavior". I've hit errors that (e.g. key-value compliant) that can be because of genuine bug in my code, or just an unclean build. I'm trying to figure out how to distinguish between the two without banging my head against the table for a couple hours until I remember about Cleaning.

Answer (score 0):

I am almost certain that XCode loses track of things and sometimes it doesn't recompile (or link, not sure) everything is needed. I have to resort to clean and build all most often than it should. Maybe it's just me, but I doubt it... XCode is the IDE with most bugs I have worked with