# Settings.bundle - Removing it?

Tags: iphone, xcode4.2

Will keep this short.  Added a settings.bundle to my app.  Didn't need it, and removed it.  Reset all content on simulator.  Force quit xCode.  Now the application prefpane is still there?!  I have no idea what I'm doing wrong.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clean the build in Xcode (Command + Shift + K). Reset simulator again. Now run (Command + R)

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it as soon as I can, and then I'll get back to you!

Comment: No problem :) You should always clean the build after deleting or replacing a file in Xcode. It doesn't seem to remove it from the IPA otherwise.

Comment: This worked for me also, what other uses are there for cleaning the build?

Comment: @EliGregory You should clean after you delete files (xcode doesn't remove the compiled file) also check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7599161/when-and-why-should-i-clean-the-build-in-xcode